# How to concatenate data where rows are the same?

Tags: sql, string-aggregation

I have a table with duplicate values in Column1 and unique values in Column2. How can I concatenate text in Column2 where duplicate values are found in Column1, without deleting duplicates.

An example of my table structure:

```
+-----------+-----------+
|  Column1  |  Column2  |
+-----------+-----------+
|  Employ1  |  Values1  |
+-----------+-----------+
|  Employ1  |  Values2  |
+-----------+-----------+
|  Employ2  |  Values3  |
+-----------+-----------+
|  Employ3  |  Values4  |
+-----------+-----------+
```

The desired output required:

```
+-----------+--------------------+
|  Column1  |       Column2      |
+-----------+--------------------+
|  Employ1  |  Values1, Values2  |
+-----------+--------------------+
|  Employ1  |  Values1, Values2  |
+-----------+--------------------+
|  Employ2  |      Values3       |
+-----------+--------------------+
|  Employ3  |      Values4       |
+-----------+--------------------+
```

I have no idea how to do this, so unfortunately cannot provide code of what I already have.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: In Postgres you can use `string_agg()`

Comment: Aggregation with group_concat() and insert into new table??

Comment: This forms part of my Qlik Sense project, so to be honest, I am not sure which DBMS product they are using. I have tried string_agg() and group_concat() now and Qlik Sense says it is not a valid built in function.

Comment: The dbms info is important. You won't find a query doing this that runs on two different dbms products.

Comment: Try `select @@version;`, `select version();`, `select * from V$VERSION;` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LEFT JOIN for SQLServer in combination with string_agg function

```
select T.column1, A.Column2
from TestT T
left join 
(select column1, string_agg(Column2, ',') Column2
from TestT
group by column1) A
on T.column1 = A.column1
```

Here you can see the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=36078cf803063d04980a00df3f944964)

For an older version of **SQLSERVER** (From SQLServer 2017 I believe the string_agg function is available...) try to create function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_select_concat ( @c varchar(50) )
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS BEGIN
DECLARE @p VARCHAR(MAX) ;
       SET @p = '' ;
    SELECT @p = @p + Column2 + ' '
      FROM TestT
     WHERE column1 = @c ;
RETURN @p
END;
```

And then call it like this:

```
SELECT column1, replace(rtrim(dbo.udf_select_concat( column1 )), ' ', ',') Column2
FROM TestT
GROUP BY column1 ;
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cdd7a3eecb5bd19808711f4f8c5d5de2)

Comment: @ben, if SQLServer is your database try this second option from my answer...

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2017, You can use STRING_AGG() function like below.

```
SELECT Column1  ,STRING_AGG(Column2,',')
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY Column1
```

Comment: This will actually remove duplicate values from column1.

Answer (score 1):

in mysql you can use `group_concat()` and for your expected result need a subquery and join with the orginal table

```
with cte as
(
select Column1,group_concat(Column2) as val from table
group by Column1
) select a.column1, cte.val from table_name a join cte on a.column1=cte.column1
```

smilar function in sql server 2017 is `STRING_AGG`  and in postgrey `STRING_AGG()` and in oracle `LISTAGG`